# Inflated AlertDialogs unreadable on Android 4.X while looking perfect on Android 2.X

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-inflate, android-version

In order to show dialogs with rich content and input elements, I use Android's `AlertDialog.Builder` to create an object of `AlertDialog` and then I use the system's `LayoutInflater` to set the content (`setView(...)`) to some XML layout file.

This looks perfect on Android 2.X (dark background, white text):

[image]

But on Android 4.X it is not readable at all:

[image]

Note: These dialogs are not the same, of course, but the problem occurs for both dialogs.

So what am I doing wrong? I'm using `Theme.Light` on API level < 11 and `Theme.Holo.Light` on >= 11.

**Edit 1:** And this is the code I use for inflating:

```
private LayoutInflater mGlobalInflater; // in Activity class
mGlobalInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); // in Activity's onCreate()
mGlobalInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null); // when needed
```

**Edit 2:** And here's the inflated XML for the "choose date" view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="15dp">
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/input_date"
        android:startYear="1900"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/hint" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit 3:** As I found out now, the inflated dialog content is rendered correctly on Android <= 2.3.3 when using `mGlobalInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` and it is rendered correctly on Android >= 3.0 when using `mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`. So the `Context` makes the difference. Why?

**Edit 4:**

The dialog is created and inflated inside of `onContextItemSelected()` of `Activity`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogPoup = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
dialogPoup.setTitle("abc123");
final View inputDialog = mGlobalInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
// setting some properties of the view and its child views
dialogPoup.setView(inputDialog);
```

Is this correct? Or do I have to replace `MainActivity.this` by a variable `mContext` (for example) that the `Activity`'s context was assigned to in `onCreate()`?

Comment: rather than posting the standard inflation code, how about the xml file?

Comment: There's nothing special about this, either ;)

Comment: i ran into something similar a while back. try explicitly setting the textcolor on the layout. you have to create different layouts for different api versions, but i think that's what you have to do.

Comment: And there's no other way? I mean, I use the standard themes and simple XML for the layout. So why does it look so bad? Is inflating views in dialogs not supported anymore with API level >= 11?

Comment: it is. the documentation wants people to switch to dialogfragments instead, but i don't think that would make a difference. see if you can specify a custom text color in your theme for api > 11 - you may have to create a style for it and set an attribute in your theme like `android:textViewStyle` or something.

Comment: So now, @toadzky, you see that the code I posted was not as meaningless as you thought ;)

Comment: Regarding _"So the Context makes the difference. Why?"_: It's because each Context can have different Theme associated with it (It's possible that the Application, the Activity and the AlertDialog.Builder each have their own theme).

Comment: But why is it that the `Application`'s context works on API level < 11 but not on > 11 and the `Activity`s context works on > 11 but not on < 11?

Comment: do you not have your theme applied to the entire application? if you do, it should give you a layoutinflater with the same properties. The only time i know you NEED to use the activity context to inflate a layout is if you are using the onClick attribute for xml-defined views. if you don't it won't find the methods.

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting the theme to the application as well. But it didn't work. So far, I've ended up choosing the `Application`'s inflater for API level < 11 and the `Activity`'s inflater for API level >= 11. But this cannot be the final solution! There must be a reason it is not working consistently?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working solution that I've found is the following:

```
    LayoutInflater mInflater, mGlobalInflater;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        mGlobalInflater = mInflater;
    }
    else {
        mGlobalInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Now you can use `mInflater` for normal inflating (such as: rows inside a `ListView`) and `mGlobalInflater` for inflating views inside of an `AlertDialog` (using `setView()`). This will then work across all API levels.

Comment: I have been unable to find a better solution myself

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting the LayoutInflater using `getApplicationContext()` like in your code above, use the one from your Activity instead like this:

```
    mGlobalInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this); // in Activity's onCreate()
```

This should hopefully use the matching theme for the dialog.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! :) But the way I invoke the `LayoutInflater` is the correct one (as referenced in the docs). You just have to replace the context: `mGlobalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` (or leave out the `this`, of course)

Comment: But unfortunately, as I've seen now, it doesn't work on Android versions prior to API level 11 anymore. There, the text is now dark and therefore not readable, either.

Comment: It worked fine for me on both API level prior and after 11. You mentioned you have several dialogs, maybe there's something special in the layout that you didn't attach to the question? Are they all in the same Activity? If they are not, each of them should acquire their own LayoutInflater from the Activity's context.

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same `Activity`. Can you reproduce the wrong behaviour on API level >= 11 when using the `Application`'s inflater?

Comment: Yes, on ICS I'm getting the white-on-white issue if I use the Application context following the sample code in your question.

Comment: Okay, please see my latest update to the question (#4) now. Maybe I've made a mistake and, when done correctly, the `Activity`'s `Context` should work in all cases ...

Comment: I tried adding the onContextItemSelected() code (as in your #4 update) to my code and am still getting the correct dialog text color for both GB (white on black) and ICS (black on white). Sorry, not sure what else could be wrong on your end - the only difference that I can note is that  I used `this` instead of `MainActivity.this`, not sure why you would need to prefix it on your side.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you're using `Theme.Light` and `Theme.Holo.Light`, it matters what you are applying this theme on.

It differs if its your `Application` or your `Activity`. If you're applying it on the `Application` level then if you get the `Context` from Application, you'd be inflating with that theme (similarly for `Activity`). You'd notice the difference if both themes are different for application vs activity.

Just keep that in mind when you're going through @Joe's answer above. You mentioned that @Joe's answer fixed the problem for api11+ but broke for those prior.

So just take a look at your AndroidManifest and see what you have for the themes for `<application>` and that particular `<activity>` that you're inflating the Dialog from.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! To me, this would have been logical as well, and the most reasonable solution. But it doesn't work. I've applied the same to the activity AND to the application, but the problem is still there.